# Android gallery tags

Tags: android, pointers, bitmap, gallery

I've currently created an Android app which plays video format and separates each frame of the video and stores it into a scrollable gallery view (unfortunately due to reputation I can't post an image of the screendump...). I want a tag or bitmap to display under certain desired frames. This will then be clickable and will allow the user to play the video from that frame. I'm really unsure as to how to go about implementing this. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to use a surface view which implements Runnable threads. I can then draw the bitmaps wherever I choose